# Lights are not working with .gltf model in A-frame 0.9 (works in 0.8)

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, gltf

I'm importing a .gltf model of a gallery and add ambient and directional lights (tried all types). Everything works as expected in 0.8.0; however, when using version 0.9.0 the interior of the model appears dark and no lights can affect it. I have to use A-frame 0.9.0 because of the added support for Oculus Go controller. 
I've been trying to figure this out all morning and still can't seem to find what the issue could be.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<!-- Changing the version to 0.8.0 eliminates the problem -->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="https://dist.3d.io/3dio-js/1.2.x/3dio.min.js"></script-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene light="defaultLightsEnabled: false">
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="room" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a8fe8e49-6e34-4c86-baec-05b8aff4571e%2Fscene.gltf?1555958013685"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="gallery" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a8fe8e49-6e34-4c86-baec-05b8aff4571e%2FGallery.fbx?1555957411386"></a-asset-item>
        <a-img id="sky" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a8fe8e49-6e34-4c86-baec-05b8aff4571e%2F47096473752_0baa631c08_o.jpg?1555959294746"></a-img>
      </a-assets>

      <a-entity position="0 -0.1 0" rotation="90 0 0" scale="50 50 1" geometry="primitive:plane"></a-entity>

      <a-entity gltf-model="#room" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="0 0.01" shadow="cast:true; receive:true;">
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity position="0.59272 4.10082 -0.40143" light="intensity:5;type:hemisphere"></a-entity>
      <a-entity position="0 1.15538 -3.77451" light="intensity:3"></a-entity>

      <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>


    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share link to glitch?

Comment: https://loud-peridot.glitch.me/

Answer (score 0):

This model uses the `KHR_materials_unlit` glTF extension, which causes it to be unaffected by lighting. Unlit – or shadeless – materials are used for better performance on mobile, and some stylized effects.

Opening the same model in other viewers you'll see the same result:

https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/#model=https://cdn.glitch.com/a8fe8e49-6e34-4c86-baec-05b8aff4571e/scene.gltf?1555958013685

^Click the info button in the lower left to see a list of extensions used by the model.

I think maybe A-Frame 0.8.0 didn't yet support this extension?

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I'm very new to 3d modeling so my question to you would be the following - can I safely turn off the mentioned extension in an app like Blender and save it so that it's affected by light? Or should I apply the light in a 3d modeling software and save it with the light applied?

Comment: Import the model in Blender 2.8 and make sure all of the meshes use a *Principled BSDF* material. Once you've done that it should export as PBR rather than unlit. More info in https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/io_gltf2.html.